# How to listen to Phone Calls in flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'll try to ask it in as simple a way as I can.
If my app is **running in foreground** and, I get a phone call at that very moment, is there any way I can call a function/perform an operation when this happens?

```
// My App is open at any random time call received
(if call_Received) { // How do I do this bit via dart code?
 sample()
}

void sample() { // Any random function
  // Some code to perform
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://pub.dev/packages/phone_state. I believe it will work for you. If you still having an issue with that, Please let me know.

Example snippet:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:phone_state/phone_state.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Example(),
    ),
  );
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  PhoneStateStatus status = PhoneStateStatus.NOTHING;
  bool granted = false;

  Future<bool> requestPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.phone.request();

    switch (status) {
      case PermissionStatus.denied:
      case PermissionStatus.restricted:
      case PermissionStatus.limited:
      case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
        return false;
      case PermissionStatus.granted:
        return true;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isIOS) setStream();
  }

  void setStream() {
    PhoneState.phoneStateStream.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        if (event != null) {
          status = event;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Phone State"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            if (Platform.isAndroid)
              MaterialButton(
                child: const Text("Request permission of Phone"),
                onPressed: !granted
                    ? () async {
                        bool temp = await requestPermission();
                        setState(() {
                          granted = temp;
                          if (granted) {
                            setStream();
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    : null,
              ),
            const Text(
              "Status of call",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
            Icon(
              getIcons(),
              color: getColor(),
              size: 80,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData getIcons() {
    switch (status) {
      case PhoneStateStatus.NOTHING:
        return Icons.clear;
      case PhoneStateStatus.CALL_INCOMING:
        return Icons.add_call;
      case PhoneStateStatus.CALL_STARTED:
        return Icons.call;
      case PhoneStateStatus.CALL_ENDED:
        return Icons.call_end;
    }
  }

  Color getColor() {
    switch (status) {
      case PhoneStateStatus.NOTHING:
      case PhoneStateStatus.CALL_ENDED:
        return Colors.red;
      case PhoneStateStatus.CALL_INCOMING:
        return Colors.green;
      case PhoneStateStatus.CALL_STARTED:
        return Colors.orange;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As https://pub.dev/packages/phonecallstate#-example-tab-package is      not working u can use new package phone_state_i 0.0.3  with https://pub.dev/packages/phone_state_i#-readme-tab-

import 'package:phone_state_i/phone_state_i.dart';

```
phoneStateCallEvent.listen((PhoneStateCallEvent event) {
      print('Call is Incoming/Connected' + event.stateC);
      //event.stateC has values "true" or "false"
});
```

Comment: Now, it seems there're a lot of packages available on pub.dev https://pub.dev/packages?q=incoming+phone+call

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/phone_state_i
but you must customize this package because you will receive a build error when you want to build apk. so customize the package and change **compileSdkVersion** from **27** to **28**.
for more information, you can see **issues** part of package.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [flutter_phone_state](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_state) plugin and it works fine for me.
But the package on the pub pub.dev is outdated and no longer maintained. So add below git url on pubspec.yaml instead.

```
  flutter_phone_state:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/flutter_phone_state.git
      ref: feature/null-safety
```

Documentation [link](https://%20%20flutter_phone_state:%20%20%20%20%20git:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url:%20https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/flutter_phone_state.git%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ref:%20feature/null-safety)